# Why is it much slower to use cut than awk to intercept two strings from each line in a file?

Tags: shell

I have a file of about 1.6 million lines, each of which is about

```
2018_08_01_02_00_00_OL13F1i5014j2513,0
2018_08_01_02_00_00_OL13F1i5055j2490,0
```

The file name is order_all.csv.

Now I have two scripts

shell one

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    st="set "
    key="$(echo $line | cut -d',' -f1)"
    value="$(echo $line | cut -d',' -f2)"
    echo "$st$key $value" >> output

done < order_all.csv
```

shell two

```
cat order_all.csv | awk -F ',' '{print "set " $1,$2}' > output
```

But I found that the second script was much faster than the first one. What's the reason?
In addition, I also hope that the newline character of every line output by the script is \r\n. What can I do about it?

Comment: the second script runs 2 commands, the first script runs `1.6M x 5` commands (roughly)

Comment: Does every command start a process? Why is it so slow to execute so many commands? I thought it would be so fast.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) is a great read about the topic.

Comment: `dos2unix file [file2 file3 ....]` will convert `\r\n` to just `\n`. Don't put them there in the first place ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Everything's relative. `cut` can easily process millions of lines per second, and you can run thousands of commands per second. However, that implies that if you run multiple `cut` commands per individual line, you're getting a really bad deal.

Comment: @shellterI'm sorry, because my machine has permission restrictions and does not allow downloading, so I hope there's a way to write a script with a line break character of \r\n.

Comment: `awk -F ',' '{print "set " $1,$2}' order_all.csv > output` to get rid of the *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`)

Answer (score 3):

As @zerkms has called out, the performance difference here is determined much more by the efficiency of the algorithms as opposed to the text processing command in play.

To understand the differences between the two, you'll want to look at how shell works compared to most other languages.  Since shell is basically individual unix programs executed one by one, the performance of each line (command really) is that of a whole program in another language, all else being the same.

What that equates to here, is that by constructing a loop around each line of data, then executing a command, 'cut', you take on the overhead of starting a new program for every line of data (and in this case 2, since you call cut 2 times around).

Behind the scenes of executing a single instance of any unix command are some very expensive operating system calls which take gobs of time, such as fork(), not to mention the process of loading the command into memory and all that's involved there.

In your second version you smartly avoid starting new commands for each line of text by use of a pipe, '|'.  This pipe streams the data to 'awk'.  Awk only starts up once in this design as it reads from STDIN a line at a time until the end of file from the stream is encountered.  'cut' can work this way (in a stream) too, but processing the text is more limited in 'cut'.  So, here the text processing occurs in a single process with the awk program loading and fork overhead done only one time while the text processing happens 1.6 million times.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I would also mention the *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`) which costs an additional 2 subshells (1 for `cat` and 1 for the pipe). `awk -F ',' '{print "set " $1,$2}' order_all.csv > output` would cure the UUOc.